# Modifying local Google Drive files from Emacs

Tags: linux, backup

Recently I've moved from MS Windows to Linux Mint.

While on windows, I used to have a code of backup in my `init.el` file, so that all emacs backups were saved into my local folder `DRIVE`, that was synced with my Google Drive cloud.

Every change I made to that folder, creating an Org file from Emacs for example, could be accessed remotely from my phone simply entering my google Drive account. In this case, my `init.el` file would contain the path of my local folder that is synced; something like `c:/user/desktop/DRIVE/backup`.

Now, on Linux Mint, this seems not to work, because Gnome does not sync a local folder, but simply displays Google Drive to me.

Although I can access it locally from my computer, paths to it do not work: I mean, I cannot add to my `init.el` file some code that creates backups in my Google Drive, because the path to the folder is super weird and does not work. The only thing I can do is create a local backup folder and then manually upload it to my Google Drive, which is not so convenient.

P.S. The backup code I use is [this one](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ForceBackups)

Comment: Lots of things to clarify if you want some help: what do you mean by a "super weird" path? What do you mean by "does not work"? Where is your local backup folder? How do you "manually upload" to Drive? Did you copy and paste the linked code literally, that is, completely unmodified?

Answer (score 1):

You might try Tramp's Google Drive integration. Try to write your backups to `/gdrive:your.name@gmail.com:/path/to/dir`.

Alternatively, you could use Tramp's `rclone` method like `/rclone:gdrive:/path/to/dir`, but this requires first to configure rclone outside Emacs for Google Drive.